# Django + Graphene, after registering a user, a confirmation letter has arrived in the developer's console. How can I get control of this email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apollo, graphene-django

I am learning Django + Graphene + React(Apollo), after registering a user, a confirmation email has come to the developer console. How can I get control of this email?

```
class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    register = mutations.Register.Field()
    verify_account = mutations.VerifyAccount.Field()
```

After I send data from the client side, the user is registered, but to confirm it, I have to perform a mutation with the token that comes in the letter.

```
mutation {
  verifyAccount(token: "YOUR TOKEN FROM LETTER") {
    success,
    errors
  }
}
```

Letter

```
<h3>{{ site_name }}</h3>

<p>Hello {{ user.username }}!</p>
<p>Please activate your account on the link:</p>

<p>{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/{{ path }}/{{ token }}</p>
```

My goal is to confirm registration via email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following code to Settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password' #my gmail password
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email' #my gmail username
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the token from the URL using JavaScript.

For example,

```
const token = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

And then send this token back to the backend using the mutation you mentioned in your question.

Comment: The problem is that it comes not to the developer's browser console, but to the django project console, and I don't know how to get control over this letter.

Comment: @Murlodin Are you saying that the token you generated never reaches the user via email? The first thing you have to do is send an email to the user, so that when the user clicks on the link provided, the token should be accessed from the UI code and sent back to the backend API.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't know how to set up sending emails, there is nothing in the documentation, after registering the html from templates is sent directly to the django console of the project. And my question is how can I get control over this data? I am using graphql_auth.

Comment: @Murlodin Sending emails is not related to GraphQL. You can search for ways to send emails in Python. For example, you can use Python libraries, such as [Python Library](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) or [SendGrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python)

Comment: I understand it. But in my opinion it is this library that sends data to the console. And the problem is that I don't even know how she does it, since I did not write any code for this. And my task is to intercept this data for further sending, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add **this email settings** for **Gmail** below to **"settings.py"** if using **Gmail**:

```py
# "settings.py"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com' # Change to your email address
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'examplePassword' # Change to your email password
```

Or, add **this email settings** for **Outlook** below to **"settings.py"** if using **Outlook**:

```py
# "settings.py"

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@outlook.com' # Change to your email address
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'example@outlook.com' # Change to your email address
SERVER_EMAIL = 'example@outlook.com' # Change to your email address
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'examplePassword' # Change to your email password
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This to settings.py:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password' #my gmail password
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email' #my gmail username
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL 'email' #my gmail username
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

- from @Murlodin

The `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` is the default for `EMAIL_FROM` in the `GRAPHQL_AUTH` config as

```py
EMAIL_FROM = getattr(django_settings, "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL", "test@email.com")
```

> so you can either change the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` or the `EMAIL_FROM` from the `GRAPHQL_AUTH` config like

```py
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    #...
    "EMAIL_FROM": 'email' #my gmail username
}
```